# Silex routing not found

Tags: php, url-routing, silex

I'm using Silex for first time. Everything works fine while developing locally.
Once uploaded everything to production server, parametrized routes don't work anymore.

Do you have any idea?
Am I missing production configurations somewhere?
Am I missing file permissions somewhere?

I'm getting those two exceptions:

```
NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /prevendita/hello/sadfasdf"
in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 92
  at RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent))
  at call_user_func(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), object(GetResponseEvent)) in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php line 164
  at EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(array(object(Application), 'onEarlyKernelRequest'), array(object(SessionServiceProvider), 'onEarlyKernelRequest'), array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(LocaleListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(Application), 'onKernelRequest')), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php line 53
  at EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 110
  at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 73
  at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php line 509
  at Application->handle(object(Request)) in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php line 484
  at Application->run() in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/web/index.php line 49
```

And:

```
ResourceNotFoundException:
in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/symfony/routing/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php line 81
  at UrlMatcher->match('/prevendita/hello/sadfasdf') in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/symfony/routing/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/RedirectableUrlMatcher.php line 30
  at RedirectableUrlMatcher->match('/prevendita/hello/sadfasdf') in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/LazyUrlMatcher.php line 51
  at LazyUrlMatcher->match('/prevendita/hello/sadfasdf') in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 78
  at RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent))
  at call_user_func(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), object(GetResponseEvent)) in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php line 164
  at EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(array(object(Application), 'onEarlyKernelRequest'), array(object(SessionServiceProvider), 'onEarlyKernelRequest'), array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(LocaleListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(Application), 'onKernelRequest')), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php line 53
  at EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 110
  at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 73
  at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php line 509
  at Application->handle(object(Request)) in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php line 484
  at Application->run() in /var/www/vhosts/teatrodellamemoria.it/httpdocs/assets/modules/prevendita/web/index.php line 49
```

This is the code:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Teatro\Models\Reservation;
use Teatro\Models\ReservationsSeat;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../views',
));
$app->register(
    new Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider()
);
$app->register(
    new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider(), array(
//        'session.storage.options' => array('name' => 'test')
    )
);
$app->register(
    new Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider()
);
$app->register(
    new Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider()
);
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
    'translator.messages' => array(),
));
$app->register(
    new Silex\Provider\SwiftmailerServiceProvider()
);

$app->get('/prevendita/hello/{name}/', function ($name) use ($app) {
    return "Hello $name!";
})->bind('hello_name');

$app->get('/prevendita/hello', function () use ($app) {
    return "Hello!";
})->bind('hello');

$app->run();
```

Development server is PHP 5.4 builtin webserver
Production server is PHP 5.3 CentOS

.htaccess files are basically the same.
In the production env, the silex app is into a subfolder of document root let's say /prevendita so I added

```
RewriteRule ^prevendita /prevendita/web/index.php [L]
```

to redirect any request starting with /prevendita to my silex app

Comment: Can you paste the stacktraces?

Comment: According to the second exception, no route matches. Maybe you can paste your routes?

Comment: problem is locally the same file works perfectly. Besides this, it works perfectly in production if the route is static. If I add a parameter in the route, it says route not found.

Comment: This is why you should paste your routing file if you want more help!

Comment: Same webserver (I mean Apache, or Nginx, or lighty on prod & dev) ? Same htaccess ? Show us the part of your controller where you might handle this route. If you only paste errors, we can't guess how the code is written ... and then can't help you.

Comment: Yes you are right. I added as much info as I could. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you not need [L,QSA] for the rewriterule?

Answer (score 9):

You wrote:

```
/prevendita/hello/{name}/
```

But requested:

```
/prevendita/hello/sadfasdf
```

You forgot the trailing slash.
I think that's the problem.

**Edit:** According to Fabien Potencier (author of Silex):

- Each resource must have a unique URL (so `/foo/` is different from `/foo`).
- As a convenience for the end user (not the developer), when a URL must end with a `/` and if he forgets to type it, Silex redirects him to the right URL (with a `/`) instead of returning a `404`.
- When Silex generate URLs, they always use the canonical URL, so the redirection is only done when a user enter a URL manually and forget to add the trailing `/`, but it is never used by the framework itself.

Comment: unfortunately this is not the case. There's an error about the trailing slash but none of the two works either with or without the trailing slash.

Comment: @Florent, is it possible to make the ending slash as optional, so that I only need to specify one route instead of two routes doing the same stuff where one route contain the ending slash and the other one doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

Best option is to point your domain to `/prevendita/web/` and not use rewrite engine to handle subdirectory. I suppose you have some other stuff under domain so maybe you can't point it to your Silex app, but you can use subdomain and instead of requesting `yourdomain.com/prevendita/web/index.php` you could request `prevendita.yourdomain.com/index.php` (with domain pointing to `web`).